# SQL Server: join data but in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Invoice` that looks similar to this:

| order_id | completed_at | subtotal | discount_amount | handling_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 07/01/2021 | 10.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | 07/04/2021 | 200.30 | 0 | 0 |
| 102 | 07/04/2021 | 54.10 | 0 | 0 |
| 103 | 07/06/2021 | 12.00 | 0 | 0 |

And I have another table `InvoiceDetail`:

| order_id | product_id | qty | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1234 | 1 | 1.09 |
| 100 | Shipping1 | 1 | 4.30 |
| 100 | SalesTax | 1 | .67 |
| 101 | 987 | 2 | 74.20 |
| 101 | 654 | 1 | 6.20 |
| 101 | Shipping2 | 1 | 5.10 |
| 101 | SalesTax | 1 | 2.30 |
| 102 | 123 | 1 | 30.15 |
| 102 | Shipping8 | 1 | 6.80 |
| 102 | SalesTax | 1 | 1.08 |
| 103 | 321 | 1 | 8.04 |
| 103 | Shipping4 | 1 | 2.05 |
| 103 | SalesTax | 1 | .70 |

I need to join the tables to look like this:

| order_id | completed_at | subtotal | shipping | sales_tax | discount_amount | handling_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 07/01/2021 | 10.09 | 4.30 | .67 | 0 | 0 |
| 101 | 07/04/2021 | 200.30 | 5.10 | 2.30 | 0 | 0 |
| 102 | 07/04/2021 | 54.10 | 6.80 | 1.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 103 | 07/06/2021 | 12.00 | 2.05 | .70 | 0 | 0 |

I have tried a few different things but every time it ends up with multiple rows for each order_id.

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    completed_at,
    subtotal,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.product_id LIKE '%Shipping%'
            THEN t2.amount 
    END AS shipping,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.product_id = 'SalesTax'
            THEN t2.amount 
    END AS sales_tax,
    discount_amount,
    handling_amount
FROM 
    Invoice t1
INNER JOIN 
    InvoiceDetail t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.InvoiceDetail
WHERE 
    order_id BETWEEN '100' AND '103'
```

The above will output the information but in multiple rows for each `order_id`. I need the order information combined with the shipping and salestax all in one row. How do I achieve what I'm after?

Comment: You may want to reconsider your table schema, if you can.  I think you'd have a much easier time if you turned things like Shipping and Sales Tax into columns for a single actual product.  I expect those would only ever have a qty of 1 so not only are you making your queries harder on yourself but you're also adding extra processing power calculating a value you should just store.

Comment: You could do a LEFT JOIN for each column or PIVOT is your keyword you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* using `CASE` inside a `SUM()` aggregation function. For example:

```
select
  i.order_id,
  max(i.completed_at) as completed_at,
  max(i.subtotal) as subtotal,
  sum(case when d.product_id like 'Shipping%' then amount end) as shipping,
  sum(case when d.product_id = 'SalesTax' then amount end) as sales_tax,
  max(i.discount_amount) as discount_amount,
  max(i.handling_amount) as handling_amount
from invoice i
left join invoicedetail d on d.order_id = i.order_id
group by i.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just need to use `SUM()` around your fields from `InvoiceDetail` and then `GROUP BY` your fields from `Invoice`:

```
SELECT  i.order_id,
        i.completed_at,
        i.subtotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN id.product_id LIKE '%Shipping%' THEN id.Amount END) AS shipping,
        SUM(CASE WHEN id.product_id = 'SalesTax' THEN id.Amount END) AS sales_tax,
        i.discount_amount,
        i.handling_amount
FROM    dbo.Invoice AS i
        INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetail AS id
            ON id.order_id = i.order_id
WHERE   i.order_id BETWEEN 100 AND 103
GROUP BY i.order_id, i.completed_at, i.subtotal, i.discount_amount, i.handling_amount;
```

*N.B I updated your join condition from `t1.order_id = t2.InvoiceDetail` as this looks like an error in the question, it is presumably `order_id` from both tables.*

*I also removed the quotes from around `100` and `103`. If `order_id` is an integer then the quotes are not necessary, if `order_id` is not an integer then `BETWEEN` is probably not the right operator to use.*

Unrelated to your question, but with SQL Server it is a good idea to get in the habit of [always including the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)(Except for the cases where you genuinely want to switch schemas based on the execution context). Another good habit is to [use meaningful table aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). If you are using `t1`, `t2`, `t3` etc this quickly gets very messy when you have large queries, `t4` gives me no information whatsoever about which table it  might be, but if you use prefixes that relate to the table itself (e.g. `i` for invoice, `id` for invoice detail), then it is much clearer when reading the code which column comes from which table.